# Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'firestore'

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

Just started using AngularFire2 v5 seeing the following error about a dozen times when I run the app: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'firestore' in the following .d.ts files:

```
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/firestore.d.ts
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts
```

I'm on "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3".

Comment: They are working on it: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1324  Hopefully it will be solved soon.

Comment: That shouldn't cause the above problems. We're using NG5 and AF5 together just fine.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I was having firebase version **4.4.0** . Then i upgraded to **4.5.0**
    npm i --save firebase@^4.5.0

***Now its working fine for me***.

Comment: Told you na.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Double check your version of `angularfire2`. It downgrades to RC0 if you do an `npm update`, which I've noticed from their issue tracker is cause for a big amount of grief.

Answer (score 1):

Also working with `npm i --save firebase@latest` then you have latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Import firebase correctly as follows:

import firebase from 'firebase/app';

then try using something like:

firebase.firestore.OrderByDirection